# Execute and Stop Many Loops Shell

Tags: linux, shell, loops, do-while

I currently have a loop this way (working perfectly):

```
while true; do /usr/bin/R_START; sleep 0.1; done
```

The script "R_START" uses the lines of a text file named "FILE.TXT", they are deleted as soon as the script executes its instructions. I wonder if it is possible to cause the "R_START" loop to be interrupted when the "FILE.TXT" file is less than 3 lines without the need for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

My biggest problem is that I need to run other "3 loops" similar to this, but I am "forced" to give <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> so I can execute the next loop.

Here's an example of what I have to do manually:
Firstly I execute:

```
while true; do /usr/bin/R_START; sleep 0.1; done
```

It shows some error messages when there are no more than 3 lines in the FILE.TXT file. That's when I give <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and continue to execute the next loop:

```
while true; do /usr/bin/R_20; sleep 0.1; done
```

It does basically the same as the first loop, and uses the same file "FILE.TXT". I see that it concluded when it shows some error messages when there are no more than 3 lines in the file "FILE.TXT". This is where I give <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and continue executing the next loop (the next one in this case will be exactly the same):

It does basically the same as the first loop, and uses the same file "FILE.TXT". I see that it concluded when it shows some error messages when there are no more than 3 lines in the file "FILE.TXT". This is where I give <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>" and continue executing the next loop (the next one in this case will be exactly the same):

```
while true; do /usr/bin/R_20; sleep 0.1; done
```

After it completes (when it shows the same message of all because it does not have more than 3 lines in the file FILE.TXT) I give <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and I manually continue to the last loop:

```
while true; do /usr/bin/R_30; sleep 0.1; done
```

The last one does exactly the same as the previous ones and I also have to give <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after it gives the error message due to not having more than 3 lines in the file "FILE.TXT".

**There would be a way to "automate" these loops:
R_START, R_20 (2x), and R_30?**

Comment: Please use the common markup - don't invent your own.

Comment: Something similar to this? `while [ $(wc -l <FILE.TXT) -lt 3 ]; do echo foo >>FILE.TXT; done` (although I make the file grow instead because it was easier).

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not quite understand. But the answer to your question is "YES". It would be something similar to this command you sent, but I have not been able to implement it yet. Would you have another example? Thank you

Comment: If you understand my suggestion, it should be easy to adapt it to your needs. Is there any particular detail you want me to explain?

Comment: I was confused with the command I needed, thank you!
It worked perfectly here!

Comment: Arndt Jonasson, If you can, put your tip that I will mark as the best answer. Thank you.